Memory leak in unknown module reported with JNA and JUnit
This is a specific issue I found while making MRE for my earlier question. It's not clear if it's the same issue, even though it seems related, so I'm asking it as a separate question.
Consider the following JUnit test class:
import com.sun.jna.Memory;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import java.lang.Integer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class MyTest {
    private void dummyTest() {
        new Memory(1024 * 9);
    }

    @Test
    public void find() {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Integer(1));

        list.stream().map(arg -> {
            Pointer ptr = new Memory(1024 * 1024);
            return ptr;
        }).toArray(Pointer[]::new);
    }

    @Test
    public void test001() {
        dummyTest();
    }

// [91 more identical tests named test002...test092 follow]

I run it on Docker Ubuntu 24.04 with packages openjdk-8-jdk clang-17 using Gradle, with address sanitizer preloaded. JNA 5.12.1, JUnit 5.8.2, host system is an up-to-date Arch Linux. Script to run it:
echo -e "leak:libjvm\nleak:libjli\nleak:libz\nleak:liblcms\nleak:liblcms2\nleak:libjavalcms\nleak:libawt\n" >> lsan.supp
export LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/llvm-17/lib/clang/17/lib/linux/libclang_rt.asan-x86_64.so"
export ASAN_OPTIONS="handle_segv=0"
export LSAN_OPTIONS="suppressions="$(pwd)"/lsan.supp:print_suppressions=0"

./gradlew clean test

It consistently produces the following leak report:
Direct leak of 1048576 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x759245cfb372 in malloc (/usr/lib/llvm-17/lib/clang/17/lib/linux/libclang_rt.asan-x86_64.so+0xfb372) (BuildId: 91f375f2a48c6b133a56d8cc059d017ae5de4982)
    #1 0x7592316185e6  (<unknown module>)
    #2 0x759231607bcf  (<unknown module>)
    #3 0x759231607bcf  (<unknown module>)
    #4 0x7592316080f5  (<unknown module>)
    #5 0x759231607e3f  (<unknown module>)
    #6 0x75923197befb  (<unknown module>)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 1048576 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).

This clearly refers to the native memory allocated on line 19. Since an instance of Memory should free the native memory on gc, I don't think it's a real leak - rather, it looks like JNA getting unloaded before that happens. However:

getting rid of the ArrayList, stream and toArray and directly creating Pointer[] ptrs = new Pointer[1]; ptrs[0] = new Memory(1024 * 1024); makes the leak report disappear
reducing the number of dummy tests makes the leak report disappear, depending on the exact number

The malloc'd native memory is never touched in my code, so I'm considering the possibility of strange behaviour related to memory overcommit.
Changing the order of tests (by changing their names since order is determined by JUnit) shows that this report appears when "find" test runs after the "dummy" tests. When "find" runs before all "dummy", checking output without suppressions reveals a different report for the same allocation:
Direct leak of 1048576 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7ec3f62fb372 in malloc (/usr/lib/llvm-17/lib/clang/17/lib/linux/libclang_rt.asan-x86_64.so+0xfb372) (BuildId: 91f375f2a48c6b133a56d8cc059d017ae5de4982)
    #1 0x7ec3e1c185e6  (<unknown module>)
    #2 0x7ec3e1c07bcf  (<unknown module>)
    #3 0x7ec3e1c07bcf  (<unknown module>)
    #4 0x7ec3e1c080f5  (<unknown module>)
    #5 0x7ec3e1c07e3f  (<unknown module>)
    #6 0x7ec3e1f75ebb  (<unknown module>)
    #7 0x7ec3e1fa91ab  (<unknown module>)
    #8 0x7ec3e1c07e3f  (<unknown module>)
    #9 0x7ec3e1c07e3f  (<unknown module>)
    #10 0x7ec3e1c07f26  (<unknown module>)
    #11 0x7ec3e1c004e6  (<unknown module>)
    #12 0x7ec3f1eb2884  (/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so+0x6b2884) (BuildId: d38655f827ac6a65fdbe1898b1278717fdb89a4e)
    #13 0x7ec3f221ac0b  (/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so+0xa1ac0b) (BuildId: d38655f827ac6a65fdbe1898b1278717fdb89a4e)
    #14 0x7ec3f221c166  (/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so+0xa1c166) (BuildId: d38655f827ac6a65fdbe1898b1278717fdb89a4e)
    #15 0x7ec3f1f66e83 in JVM_InvokeMethod (/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so+0x766e83) (BuildId: d38655f827ac6a65fdbe1898b1278717fdb89a4e)
    #16 0x7ec3e1c185e6  (<unknown module>)
    #17 0x7ec3e1c07e3f  (<unknown module>)
    #18 0x7ec3e1c07e3f  (<unknown module>)
    #19 0x7ec3e1c07f26  (<unknown module>)
    #20 0x7ec3e1c07e3f  (<unknown module>)
    #21 0x7ec3e1c07e3f  (<unknown module>)
    #22 0x7ec3e1c07f26  (<unknown module>)
    #23 0x7ec3e1c07f26  (<unknown module>)
    #24 0x7ec3e1c07e3f  (<unknown module>)
    #25 0x7ec3e1c07e3f  (<unknown module>)
    #26 0x7ec3e1c0813a  (<unknown module>)
    #27 0x7ec3e1c0813a  (<unknown module>)
    #28 0x7ec3e1c07e3f  (<unknown module>)
    #29 0x7ec3e1c07f26  (<unknown module>)

There are many other (most likely false positive due to GC) leaks reported, but in my experiments, none of them ever exhibit this behaviour where depending on order of tests, only asan and <unknown module>s appear, without any known Java library - although it could just be possible but very rare for other leak reports. In different experiments, they have different number of bytes allocated in different number of allocations, but there's always at least one Java library (typically libjvm.so) reported.
Despite ASLR, it's possible to track same calls in the trace by least significant bytes of addresses. In the leak reports shown here and all others corresponding to the same allocation in different experiments/runs, addresses #0-#5 always end with the same bytes, but for address #6, they vary.
I made a full repo to conveniently reproduce this error by calling run.sh. All relevant information and code is copied to this question.
My question here is: what exactly causes this specific leak report to contain only asan and <unknown module>s? To be clear, I don't care here if <unknown module> appears sometimes, as long as there's always at least one known library (non-asan) that I can use to suppress.

It could be helpful if you can try to reproduce this leak in 5.11 or earlier, or 5.13 or later versions to see if it's associated with the new Cleaner for memory introduced in 5.12.x.
